# Generate a List of External Users for SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, permissions, pnp-powershell, external-users

Is there a way to generate a list of all External Users for the Entire SharePoint Online Tenant?

Answer (score 1):

You can list all external users for the entire SharePoint Online tenant by using following option.

Method 1:  Use PnP PowerShell to list all external users.

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com"

Get-PnPExternalUser
```

For more details use this link [List external users](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Get-PnPExternalUser.html)

Method 2: Use graph api to list all external users

```
Use below endpoint
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$filter=userType eq 'guest'
```

Please mark as answer if you are satisfied and upvote it.

Comment: HI Tejas, did you tried above solution

Comment: Hi Rajat, I Tried using Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com"

Get-PnPExternalUser - But it give me 403 Forbidden error, any ideas?

Comment: PnP-PowerShell must be approved by your admin before you used it.

Comment: Yes i have all the required permissions!

Comment: try this Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com" -Interactive

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get the list of external users using SharePoint online PowerShell or PnP PowerShell.

**Sample script 1**:

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://office365admin123-admin.sharepoint.com-credential $credentials
$i = 0  
ForEach($site in Get - SPOSite)  
{  
    $i++  
    Write - Host "*********"  
    Write - Host "Site number: "  
    $i  
    $site.Url  
    $site.Owner  
    $site.SharingCapability  
    Get - SPOExternalUser - SiteUrl $site.Url  
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Source**: [Report On External Users In SharePoint Online](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/report-on-external-users-in-sharepoint-online)

---

**Sample script 2**:

```
#Import SharePoint Online Management Shell
Import-Module Microsoft.Online.Sharepoint.PowerShell -DisableNameChecking
 
#Config Parameters
$AdminSiteURL="https://crescent-admin.sharepoint.com"
$ReportOutput ="C:\Temp\ExternalUsersRpt.csv"
 
#Get Credentials to connect
$Cred = Get-Credential
 
#Connect to SharePoint Online Tenant Admin
Connect-SPOService -URL $AdminSiteURL -Credential $Cred
 
#Get All Site Collections
$SiteCollections  = Get-SPOSite -Limit All
 
#Iterate through each site collection and get external users
Foreach ($Site in $SiteCollections)
{
    Write-host -f Yellow "Checking Site Collection:"$Site.URL
    Try {
        For ($x=0;;$x+=50) {
            $ExternalUsers += Get-SPOExternalUser -SiteUrl $Site.Url -Position $x -PageSize 50 -ErrorAction Stop | Select DisplayName,EMail,InvitedBy,AcceptedAs,WhenCreated,@{Name = "SiteUrl" ; Expression = {$Site.url} 
        }
    }
}
catch {}
}
 
#Export the Data to CSV file
$ExternalUsers | Export-Csv -Path $ReportOutput -NoTypeInformation
```

**Source**: [SharePoint Online: Find All External Users using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/11/sharepoint-online-find-all-external-users-using-powershell.html) - You can also find the other ways to fetch external users in this reference.

Comment: I tried this one, but i see that it's generating data for only the Root sites, Anyway to get data of the sub-sites as well?

Comment: Did you try 2nd script? You can also try the different ways (Site Collection Wise or using PnP PowerShell) given in 2nd link in my answer.

Comment: Sample script 2: - I Tried this script

Comment: So, is it not returning all external users as expected?

Comment: It's returning the results, but only with the Root site, and not the sub sites!

Answer (score 0):

You can use scripts mentioned above or directly use the cmdlet

```
$AdminSiteURL="https://<domain>-admin.sharepoint.com"
$Cred = Get-Credential
Connect-SPOService -URL $AdminSiteURL -Credential $Cred
Get-SPOExternalUser
```

It will directly list all the external users.

Reference:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/get-spoexternaluser?view=sharepoint-ps

And you can directly goes to the Azure AD and filter users based on user type. All the guests will be displayed.